# php process email subject with mb_decode_mimeheader, add to SimpleXML object and asXML outputs wrong characters

Tags: php, character-encoding, simplexml

I am processing emails with a script.

I'm experiencing an odd issue when processing subjects that come encoded.

This is my test source code:

```
<?php
$original='=?UTF-8?B?UHJvYsOzIE3DoXMgVmVjZXM=?=';
$decoded = mb_decode_mimeheader($original);

$obj = new SimpleXMLElement('<' . '?' . 'xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?' .'><request></request>');
$obj->addChild('subject', $decoded);

print_r($obj);

print "<br><br>";

print $obj->asXML();
?>
```

This is the output it produces (source code of output):

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[subject] => Probó Más Veces
)
<br><br><?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<request><subject>Prob&#xE0361;s Veces</subject></request>
```

As you can see, in the SimpleXML object, the subject is correct "Probó Más Veces" but in the asXML output, it has been converted to : Prob󠍡s Veces.

Any ideas why it is behaving like this and how I could solve this issue?

Thanks!